# Why the fallback route always got triggered? Even though another route hit first

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Why user accesses **#app/react/index**

Both index and FallbackPage are triggered. Why?

```
    <Router basename={`<URL>#app/react}>
        <Switch history={history}>
            <div className={`layout`}
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    .....
                </nav>
                <Route exact path='/index'>
                    <h1>Index</h1>
                    .....
                </Route>
                <Route path="/"
                    component={FallbackPage}/>
            </div>
        </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap Route with Switch directly.

```
<Router basename={`<URL>#app/react}>
    <div className={`layout`}
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                .....
        </nav>
        <Switch history={history}>
            <Route exact path='/index'>
                <h1>Index</h1>
                .....
            </Route>
            <Route path="/"
                component={FallbackPage}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are both hit since the `Switch` component is rendering a single `div` element. It's like being rendered by a normal router where all routes are matched and rendered inclusively.

You could move the nav and the layout div out of the `Switch` so it's wrapping and rendering only the `Route` components. Once you are rendering the routes directly into the `Switch` and ordering them from more specific to less specific paths, you won't need to specify the `exact` prop on the "/index" route.

```
<Router basename={'<URL>#app/react'}>
  <div className={'layout'}>
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      .....
    </nav>
    <Switch history={history}>
      <Route path='/index'>
        <h1>Index</h1>
        .....
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" component={FallbackPage}/>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```